# LTI library for ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, moodle, lti

I have a application which is developed in ASP.NET MVC5. I want to integrate it with Moodle. I have no idea about this PHP open source. Can anybody direct me how i can achieve this? I read somewhere about the LTI library for MVC but couldnt find any in googling..

anybody please help...

Comment: How or what do you want to integrate? What does the .net application do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C# .NET LTI library: https://github.com/andyfmiller/LtiLibrary

And the author is working on an Microsoft.AspNet.Identity compatible version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LtiLibrary.AspNet.Identity.Owin/